# Query for not like sql

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables, employees and vehicles.

- Employees (emp_id,first_name ,last_name)
- Vehicles (vehicle_id, vehicle_type, emp_id)

Let say the vehicle type have value car and motorcycle.

Some of employee do not have car and motorcycle, some of employee only have car or motorcycle, some of employee have both car and motorcycle.

My question is How to get the employee which don't have car?

Below is my query but the result is wrong as it still get the employee which have both car and motorcycle.

```
SELECT e.emp_id,e.first_name, e.last_name,v.vehicle_type
FROM employees e 
LEFT JOIN vehicles v
ON e.emp_id= v.emp_id
WHERE NOT vehicle_type='car' 
GROUP BY e.emp_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more intuitive answer,
First get the employees who has a car - that's easy

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_id
FROM employees e JOIN vehicles v
                      ON e.emp_id= v.emp_id 
WHERE v.vehicle_type='car'
```

Now you can easily get the list of the other employeese

```
SELECT e.emp_id,e.first_name, e.last_name,v.vehicle_type
FROM employees e LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles v
                               ON e.emp_id= v.emp_id 
WHERE e.emp_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT e.emp_id
                       FROM employees e JOIN vehicles v
                                             ON e.emp_id= v.emp_id 
                       WHERE v.vehicle_type='car' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM   employees e 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   vehicles v
                   WHERE e.emp_id = v.emp_id AND vehicle_type = 'car'
                  )
```